# How to search for text in a binary file in Dart

Tags: dart, binary

I am trying to search the binary data of a file in dart, to find the index of a substring. I have working js code but I am unable to convert it to dart. This is the js snippet:

```
var rp = require('request-promise');

async function test(){
    const uri = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/04/file_example_MP4_480_1_5MG.mp4"
    const result = await rp({ uri });
    const position = Buffer.from(result).indexOf('dnlu');
    console.log(position);
}

test() //outputs 2631582
```

What would be the dart equivalent of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll typically fetch the bytes as a `Uint8List`.
The Dart `Uint8List` does not have an `indexOf` method which works on sublists, so you'll have to search the old fashioned way - by looking at it.
I assume that the bytes represent UTF-8 or Latin-1 characters, and since your string contains only ASCII, you can search for the code units directly.

Maybe you could add something like:

```dart
extension IndexOfListExtension<T> on List<T> {
  int indexOfAll(List<T> needle, [int start = 0]) {
    if (needle.length == 0) return start;
    var first = needle[0];
    var end = this.length - needle.length;
    for (var i = start; i <= end; i++) {
      match:
      if (this[i] == first) {
        for (var j = 1; j < needle.length; j++) {
          if (this[i + j] != needle[j]) break match;
        }
        return i;
      }  
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Then you would be able to do:

```
  var bytes = await fetch_the_bytes(uri); // However you want to do this.
  var position = bytes.indexOfAll("dnlu".codeUnits);
  ...
```

Comment: Perfect! I modified your solution to create an "indexOf" extension instead that converts the string to codeUnits within the exFunc.Thanks.